# Air conditioner not blowing cold air

Tags: hvac

My HVAC system had a problem during the winter where the blower motor stopped working. 
I got a HVAC tech to come out and replace it.

However, now that it's hot again, the cooling system is still being problematic.

Basically, the air being blown into the house is not cool enough to reduce the temperature in the house. This causes the system to run continuously for days without ever shutting down.

What may be the cause?

Comment: Consider slipping a bit more detail into the original question: "My air conditioner blower is running, but air coming out of the registers is not cold. How can I find the problem?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of possible causes, but you may need an HVAC repair man to diagnose it.  The first thing they'll check is the refrigerant levels (Freon, Puron, or whatever your system is using).  If it's low, there may be a leak, possibly caused during the blower motor replacement.

Simple things you can verify yourself are that the outside unit is unobstructed to allow air to pass in the sides and out the top.  If it isn't even turning on, either your refrigerant levels are so low the compressor is staying off for safety, or perhaps it's as simple as a wire not being plugged back in from the thermostat to the inside unit.  The owners manual should include a wiring diagram.

Another simple thing to check are any filters either on the return vents or at the blower itself.  And finally, open up any access panel you can on the condenser coils and make sure they are clean and free of ice.

Answer (score 0):

Mine just do the same thins after 3 years of almost always "on" operation. Think about going to repair/refill the freon, or get a new one. But before that.

1) i unmount, dismantle everything that can be, and clean it with water, hose, degreeser, pressure water, scott tower, more water, more air, and let it dry for a day dismantle.

2) put back everything togeter....

3) have another 3 years of perfect functionning

4) sold the hous with the air condition device install, so cannot tell for the futur

have fun !

- note, i get about a pound of cat hair, leaf, dust and "other" thing out with a stick. At start it look like fur insite the a/c, now it out, dont belong there !